# Tag search and info won't work with non-ASCII tags

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, ios-app

For example, ["アルゴリズム"](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B4%E3%83%AA%E3%82%BA%E3%83%A0) tag in ja.SO has a wiki summary and 80 over questions.

If I tap the tag to search, the app shows... unrelated questions.

[image: tag search]

and there is no tag info.

[image: tag info]

I've also seen this problem in [pt.SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exce%C3%A7%C3%A3o) and [ru.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fixed with the latest API build. (No app update required.)

Non-ASCII tags are allowed on a per-site basis.  When the app went to sanitize the tag for search, it checked against the API site, which doesn't have non-ASCII tags so it removed every non-ASCII character and in the first case effectively search for all question and in the second case looked for the wiki on a tag with no name.

The update will sanitize tags correctly based on the site in the request.